# PHP: transfer big file using ftp_get()

Tags: file

i´m trying to transfer a large file (~2.5GB) using ftp_get().
after starting transfer i see the file appearing on ftp and counting up.
at the end the file disappears. any ideas?

smaller files (up to 100mb) have no problems.

code is really simple ;)

```
return @ftp_get($obj_ftp, $str_target, $str_source, FTP_BINARY);
```